# How do I block a country using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a lot of traffic from Russia which I want to block. Is there any way to do this using .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

Just use one of the available public services to generate a list of the IP ranges you want to block. For instance, [see this one](http://services.ce3c.be/ciprg/) or [this one](https://www.countryipblocks.net/country_selection.php).